# How to remove the default 0 value of <InputNumber/>

Tags: blazor

I want to get rid of default 0 that is in every `<InputNumber/>` element in blazor.
Using the `Value=""` doesn't work.

Here i have one of the many `<InputNumber/>` elements i have

```html
<label>@OrderNumber</label>
<br />
<InputNumber class="input" @bind-Value="label.OrderNumber" />
<br />
```

edit: i would like to do this without any javascript

Comment: is your bind-value on the model a nullable type? if not try using nullable int / decimal / float.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your model (add "?" to tell your model that it can be NULL):

```
[Required]
public int? PostalCode { get; set; }
```