# Why is the number zero in the field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, blazor

Tell me how to remove the number zero from the input field. How do I make a field empty?
I not found descriptions this moment in documentations.

Thank you for your help!

```cs
 public class Bag
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Обязательное поле")]
        public long Bag_id { get; set; }

        //public DateTime Report_Date { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName ="decimal(4,2)")]
        public decimal Weigth { get; set; }
}
```

AddBags.razor

```html
@page "/AddBags"
@using Extrasil.Data
@using Extrasil.Data.Models
@using Extrasil.Data.Controllers
@inject BagController objAddBags
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h3>Добавить мешок</h3>

<hr />
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Bag_id" class="custom-label">Номер мешка</label>
                <input form="Bag_id" class="form-control" @bind="@bag.Bag_id" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Weigth" class="custom-label">Вес</label>
                <input form="Weigth" class="form-control" @bind="@bag.Weigth" />
            </div>
...
```

[image: Picture with my problem]

Comment: integer default value is 0.

Comment: Hhmm...Ok, how i make field is empty? With out "0"?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61117077/1981247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change the type to a nullable of long. The default value for long is 0 so if you bind to it you will get 0. `Nullable<long>` or `long?` defaults to `null` and might be the effect you want. Try changing the definition of your properties.

```
public class Bag
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Обязательное поле")]
        public long? Bag_id { get; set; }

        //public DateTime Report_Date { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName ="decimal(4,2)")]
        public decimal? Weigth { get; set; }
}
```

If you make those changes you will still be able to assign long and decimal values to those properties respectively but it will no longer default to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the `long` properties to nullable `long?`, see below:

```cs
public class Bag
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public long? Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Обязательное поле")]
    public long? Bag_id { get; set; }
}
```

And as I can see that you are using the same model for database and view, you can create a separate view model and add nullable properties in it and keep the database entity model as non-null.

Comment: Thanks for the idea to use different models for the database and view! I'll try!