# Blazor, fill 0 value binded property as empty string in input

Tags: c#, blazor

Hi I have a question,

So I am experimenting with blazor and it has been fun but I was wondering when I bind a simple model, with one int property to a text input for example:

```
<input type="text" class="communication__control--input" id="broadcast-port" autocomplete="off" placeholder=" " @bind="@this.Simple.Number" />
```

Now property in model is just int (not nullable) so default value would be 0 for that input. So my question is can I make that 0 will show as an empty string in input and still if I write any value (for example 3 will show as 3 but 0 will show empty string) to it it will bind?

Basing @Bennyboy1973 comment, basically I could go with 2 properties one that will be binded string prop and other would be read only int that will try to convert first one, or just use 2 model combination (something like DTO and backend model) with automapper. But is there any simpler way?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing any of what you're showing right now.  @bind is for 2-way binding, which means that changes to the string will update in the input AND vice versa.  This requires a matching data type.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61117077/1981247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it this way, then this works:

```
    <input type="text" @bind-value="model.Value" />

@code {

    public class Model
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Value
        {
            get => _value != 0 ? _value.ToString() : string.Empty;
            set
            {
                if (int.TryParse(value, out int pvalue))
                    _value = pvalue;
                else
                    _value = 0;
            }
        }

        private int _value;
    }
```

I can foresee a problem or two with more advanced situations in validation and edit state management, so I would probably write a custom version of the Blazor `InputText`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nullable value type, for example `decimal?` instead of `decimal`

```
<input @bind="price" placeholder="0.00" type="text" />

@code {
    public decimal? price = null;
}
```